# Connecting conductors with different Fermi levels. Properties of a reservoir

Tags: mesoscopic-physics

Suppose we have a reserve whose chemical potential is $\mu_{A}$. There is a conductor whose chemical potential is $\mu_{B}$. $\mu_{A}>\mu_{B}$. We connect the conductor with the reservoir. What happens to the flow of electrons? Do the electrons start moving into the conductor. When the electrons flow into the conductor, does the Fermi level starts rising? Does the electron flow continue until the to Fermi levels become equal? Suppose we connect, to the other end of the conductor, another reservoir at chemical potential $\mu_{C}$ with $\mu_{B}>\mu_{C}$. Does there start happening a continuous flow of electrons through the conductor? What are the properties of such conduction? Do we provide the conductance through Landauer conductance formula?

My other question is that how can we make a reservoir? Even after losing many electrons, the chemical potential of the reservoir should remain intact. For fermions, we can't have a degeneracy of higher than two. Should we have a very-very high density of states near the Fermi level then, to make a reservoir? Is it so that as we keep rising in energy, the density of the energy levels also keeps rising. So if it is true then should we have a very very electron rich conductor to achieve a reservoir? Because as we keep increasing the number of electrons the new electrons should enter the higher energy levels. What role does the size of the reservoir have to play? Should the reservoir be very big?